# Parse formatted text from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to get all the texts from a Google Spreadsheet and populate it into my website using JavaScript, but I need the spreadsheet text as it's on the spreadsheet, formatter with bold, italic, etc.

Is there a way to parse formatted text from Google Spreadsheet without having to publish online the spreadsheet?

Comment: It's not clear how "having to publish online" is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can, see full documentation of Google Spreadsheet API [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js).

As detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet), to read data from your spreadsheet in js, you will need :

1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API and check the quota for your project at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
2. Get access keys for your application. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#get-access-keys-for-your-application

Then you will be able to build your script. See the examples on the previous link, pretty well detailed. You are even able to test the API on the same page (see end).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look.